# "The specified report server url could not be found" error while deploying to reporting server

Tags: reporting-services

I want to deploy a report that I have created in SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008 R2. I have set `TargetServerURL` to `http://mohammad-pc/Reports`. I can access this path through a browser, but want to deploy my report I get:

> "the specified report server url could not be found"

Is there any other setting that I missed?

Answer (score 38):

Typically, in a default installation, you'll have two URL's:

- `http://yourmachine/ReportServer` - [for accessing the web service and deploying reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159261.aspx)
- `http://yourmachine/Reports` - for accessing the browser-based management front-end

Depending on your setup, the first URL may differ a bit, for example the port number may be different or a suffix like `_SQLEXPRESS` may be added.

See also the last section of [this documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630447.aspx) for some example URLs. Here's a relevant quote on what the links may look like:

> ...what a report server URL might resemble:
>    - `http://localhost/reportserver`
>    - `http://localhost/reportserver_SQLEXPRESS`
>    - `http://sales01/reportserver`
>    - `http://sales01:8080/reportserver`
>    - `https://sales.adventure-works.com/reportserver`
>    - `https://www.adventure-works.com:8080/reportserver01`
>
> ...URLs that you use to access Report Manager...
>    - `http://localhost/reports`
>    - `http://localhost/reports_SQLEXPRESS`
>    - `http://sales01/reports`
>    - `http://sales01:8080/reports`
>    - `https://sales.adventure-works.com/reports`
>    - `https://www.adventure-works.com:8080/reports`

Comment: Changing it to ReportServer did the trick for me. Thank you @Jeroen

Comment: to be clear, you set this by going to FILE--> Project --> <projectName> Properties.    F4 or rightclick-->properties in the solution explorer will not show you what you think it might

Comment: Appending "ReportServer" is what worked for me; I had been trying the URL, which was "http://<serverName>/Reports" (which is the URL to get to the reports) but that didn't work - "http://<serverName>/ReportServer" does - thanks!

Answer (score 15):

I found the solution. My URL is wrong. To get the correct URL I went to Start menu > SQL Server 2008 > Configuration Tools > Reporting Services Configuration. On Web Service URL section there is a Virtual Directory that is the directory of my SSRS directory on my computer. So the correct URL is "http://localhost/[Reporting Service Virtual directory]". In my case it is "http://localhost/ReportServer_SQL2008".

There is a good article here:

http://alexduggleby.com/2008/07/18/sql-server-reporting-services-2008-tutorial-in-5-minutes-or-how-to-send-my-boss-a-report-from-a-view-quickly/

Comment: Just to add here. This is to correct way to get the URL but I got some problems with the browser security. So instead you can go to: <http://YourServerName/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx>

And remember to run the browser As Administrator

Answer (score 3):

recently I was having the same issues... Testing I found that you need go to Project -> Properties and in General and change the set the following options to:

> TargetReportPartFolder: [Virtual Diretory of Report Manager URL] 
>   TargetServerURL: http://yourPCName/[Virtual Diretory of Web Service URL]

Thats work good for deploy your project

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this, I also came upon this problem. My report server was working fine for months, I've got around 30 reports and make constant updates to them re deploying reports or creating new ones almost every week, however it just stopped deploying one day (although I could see them in the application we have bound them to)

The error was a **502 host not found**. I have a feeling it was something to do with IT making changes in my company however all I needed to do to fix it was change the report server name to local host in the property settings.

Project / [Project Name] Properties

> on the general tab in the TargetServerURL it used to say:
>
> http://GSV-REP01/ReportServer

but then I changed it to this:

> http://localhost:8080/ReportServer

and it started working again with no problems. Hope this helps someone, SSRS is a real pain sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `http://localhost/reportserver` or `http://mohammad-pc/reportserver` as TargetServerURL in the project properties.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10181323)

Comment: @Heroka I improved the answer.

Comment: @greg121 the answer won't solve the question. Your solution only will work in the case the user is developing the report in the same pc where will be deployed, and it isn't a standard case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do these steps to get the correct Report Service URL

1. Open Reporting Services Configuration Manager, you can search it via windows start  button
2. You will be prompted with dialog to connect to available reporting service database, click Connect.
3. Select Report Manager URL, you will see your url in there, usually the pattern would be http://**YOURHOSTNAME**:80/Reports_**SQLVERSION**