# SSRS error after I created a new folder in the "Report Manager" website?

Tags: reporting-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“the specified report server url could not be found” error shile deploying reporting server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279871/the-specified-report-server-url-could-not-be-found-error-shile-deploying-repor)

I was organizing the reports on my "Report Manager" web-page, and I created a new folder and moved some reports in it.

Afterwards  I got the following error  in SSRS:

> TargetServerURL is not valid. Specify a valid URL for a report server
>   in the deployment settings

[image]

The URL from within the new foler is `http://10.0.1.106/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fSurveyLevel&ViewMode=Detail` (is this the relevant URL)

And here's a screenshot of the "Report Manager" page -

[image]

Comment: Can you share the URL you are using? Are you just trying to get to the main folder?

Comment: OK sure, i'll add a SS and URL

Comment: @Neil - Is the URL the one from the address-bar of IE?

Comment: Yes. So when you go to open the folder is that when you are getting the error?

Comment: @Neil - No, i can open the folder.   Hmm, on second thought, maybe this was a one-time glitch?

Comment: Well let me know if you encounter it in the future.

Comment: Have you edited the TargetServerURL in deployment settings for the project? I think you need to as you have moved the reports to another folder.